# Repeat a text box on every Word page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I'm building a template to be used by teachers to create their exams.

I want to have a text box on the left of every page, where the scores for each exercise can be typed.

Apparently the master page feature has been depricated in Word 2016, so I'm looking for alternatives.

Currently I'm placing the text box in the header/footer, but now teachers have to double click in the header/footer before they can type in the text box.

Are there any better/user friendly possibilities?

Edit: my workaround is no good either, because I would need to create different sections for every page, otherwise the text box content will be the same on all pages.

Comment: I don't know of any master page feature in prior versions of word. From what I know word doesn't have a concept of different kinds of pages. That would be either Publisher or PowerPoint. VBA might offer an option for this but it's going to be way more complicated.

Comment: @Seth, Word for Mac has – or at least used to have, in the 2011 version – a Publishing layout view that includes master pages functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a text box, format and position it exactly as you want it to appear, and even add default text to it. Then select the text box, and save it to the Text Box Gallery (on the **Insert** tab, in the **Text** group, click **Text Box** > **Save Selection to Text Box Gallery**). You can then quickly insert a copy on every page by selecting in on the **Text Box** drop-down.

(Tip: When you're saving the text box to the gallery, in the **Category** field, click **Create New Category**, and enter a name that starts with a special character, such as * or _; that way, your text box will always be the topmost option in the **Text Box** drop-down.)

If you want a script that that will add a text box to every page for you, you may be able to adapt the answer on [this Office forum page](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/19239-add-text-box-each-page-word-doc.html).